# The constructor (constructor name) is undefined

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to create a code to eventually be able to calculate the area and perimeter of rectangles with their dimensions from user input. As of now when I try to call my rectangle class to create a new rectangle, the compiler says the rectangle constructor is undefined.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rectangles {

  public class rectangle {
    public rectangle() {}
    public int length;
    public int width;
    public rectangle(int len, int wid) {
      length = len;
      width = wid;

    } 

  }

  public void runner() {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input1 = scanner.nextLine();
    String input2 = scanner.nextLine();
    rectangle first = new rectangle(input1, input2); //Error here
    System.out.println(first);
    scanner.close();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

The error is "The constructor rectangles.rectangle(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) is undefined"

Comment: Your constructor accepts `int` but you are calling it with `String` arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is as the compiler has stated - you have declared a constructor that takes two `int` arguments, but tried to create a `rectangle` using two `String`s. The types are incompatible. You should either use your scanner to read an `int` or use one of the utility methods in the `Integer` class to convert the `String` to an `int` or `Integer`. You should also be aware of coding standards such as capitalised class names.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `rectangle` class `private` and each `public` class usually needs to be in its own compilable file.

Also the constructor that youy have defined takes `int` but you are passing `String`

Consider using `Integer.parse (input1);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use the correct Java conventions. This means that type names are `PascalCase`, and variable/method names are `camelCase`.

You've created a constructor for `rectangle` which takes two `int`s, but you are passing two `String`s. The `Scanner` class has a convenience method for getting an `int` from input: [`Scanner#nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()).

You should refactor your code so that `input1` and `input2` are `int` types:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int input1 = scanner.nextInt();
int input2 = scanner.nextInt();
rectangle first = new rectangle(input1, input2);
```